# How to increase the font size of result text in Azure Data Studio Notebook?

Tags: sql, azure-data-studio

I have found how to increase the font size of about everything except the result text of a code cell in an Azure Data Studio notebook.  Zoom works, but is not ideal.  Does anyone know of a way to increase the font size of that text?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I have found that using the zoom-in and zoom-out shortcuts ('ctrl+' and 'ctr-' for me) will also increase the text size in the notes/messages pane.
- I am using version 1.28.0 and it works that way.
- By hitting 'ctrl+shift+p' will also pop up the command palette where you can further customize the shortcuts after searching for 'zoom'.

I hope it will help you, too.

Comment: I second the above solution! I had searched the Command Palette for 'font' rather than 'zoom' which revealed no useful controls. Until today, I didn't know that the font sizes on the View panes and the Editor panes were independently controllable. The only limitation is that the 'View: Zoom In' and 'View: Zoom Out' appear to apply to all non-editor panes, so if you want your Results pane smaller, you'll also have to live with your Extensions/Connections/Notebooks/etc. views smaller.

Answer (score 3):

I started using Azure Data Studio with version 1.41.2 and in Settings there are options for results grid area to configure font related settings like font family, size, weight, etc.

[Result Grid Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC7BL.png)

Comment: Consider updating your answer to explain how it increases the font size of the result text.

Comment: Here's how I did this: F1 -> search "Preferences: Open User Settings" -> search "results grid: font size" -> change font size to meet your needs